# QGIS buffer zone error larger than 3000km

Tags: buffer, gis, qgis

I am running buffer zones for specific points on a reprojected layer and get errors when the buffer zone is larger than 3000km. Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it? Thanks for your help! :)

Process:
A csv with a series of coordinates is added as a delimited text layer. This layer is reprojected from decimal degrees to standard UTM. A series of buffer zones are created for the reprojected layer. A strange error occurs when the buffer zone size is greater than 3000km (see image).

[image: Buffer zone glitch at 3300km]

The buffer zone error does not occur for all points on the layer, only for some. The extent of the glitch also changes slightly depending on the choice of standard UTM when reprojecting the layer.

Comment: What is it "standard UTM"? Maybe you are using the wrong UTM, or some points may be out it. In any case, your question is off-topic for this site. This site is about programming. We have a sister site (links on top right icon) about GIS. I think your question is more appropriate there (but give more details).

Comment: pretty sure 3000km is wider than a UTM zone (though I can't be bothered to do the math just now)